# Can't find class/add reference universal windows

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I'm working on a personal project with VS 2015/Universal app solution and i try to follow this code sample :

[Asynchronous Server Socket Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx)

But when i want to create a new `IPHostEntry` or make a `Dns.GetHostName()`  VS don't find the assembly.

I have these references on my solution explorer :

```
Analyzer
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PersistenceChannel
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsApps
Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform
Universal Windows
```

and the using directives following :

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Collections.ObjectModel; 
using System.Diagnostics; 
using System.IO; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Net; 
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks; 
using System.Xml; 
using System.Xml.Serialization; 
using System.Net.Sockets;
```

I tried also to add `System.Net dll` manually (located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6) to the solution references but i got an error telling me that the component is already automatically added by the generation system.

Comment: Did you use .NETFramework 4.5/4.6 as a target framework?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I cant target a specific framework in the options of my solution, i have just " target : Universal Windows" with no choices

Comment: Sorry? I guess you did not understand me correctly. I mean what target framework you use in Properties -> Application in your project([link](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC712091.jpeg))? And it was not an answer, it was a question

Comment: thanks again, i have understand what you mean i think, i want to show you by a screenshot but i dont know if i have the right, you can see here : http://hpics.li/9b1fa97
so i have not a lot of choices as you can see, and there is no other choices for target version/min version

Comment: Ok, did you try to remove System.Net and added it again?

Comment: I cant remove System.net from the references cause its not a reference... i should miss something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Store Apps use a different version of .Net framework, which does not contain many of the classes of the "regular" .Net framework, the functionality for some of the missing classes might be offered under a different namespace and type.

Take a look at these pages for more details:

[.NET for Windows Store apps overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh454046.aspx)

[System.Net namespaces for UWP apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185489.aspx)

It seems  to me that the interfaces and methods you are trying to use are not available.

**Edit from comments:**
There is a [StreamSocket sample for UWP in MSDN](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/StreamSocket)

Comment: thanks for the answer, i will just add for complete the thread this answer from [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/fr-FR/7a8e6e6d-55fe-46fb-8344-07692132144c/uwp-cant-find-classadd-net-reference-universal-windows?forum=wpdevelop) who contain a link to a UWP socket sample.